# How to paste clipboard data to another application in c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form where i have copied a text in clipboard, now my requirement is that after setting clipboard data if i click in inside another application like notepad
data gets pasted there.

```
 private void ListView1_EPC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ListView1_EPC.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;            
        Clipboard.SetText(str);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You would probably need a separate app that attaches to the Win32 Windows Extensions...

Comment: I found this, it will send keys to specific Window via Windows API: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/send-keys-to-application-programmatically-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

That is possible: You can attach to the system wide mousedown. This has already been implemented in C#, have a look here... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C
This project provides a simple event for a global mouse down (GlobalEventProvider component). What you then need to do is to send a ctrl-v using SendKeys, when this mouse down has been triggered...

```
public class ForeignWindowPasteHelper
{

private readonly GlobalEventProvider eventProvider = new GlobalEventProvider();

  public ForeignWindowPasteHelper()
  {
    this.eventProvider.MouseClick += this.GlobalMouseDown;
  }

  private void GlobalMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
  }
}
```

This will trigger a Cntrl+V (Insert) on every keydown. You will need to implement some logic, when this needs to be triggered. But thats not hard.